# In Maxwell's equations concerning dielectric materials , does the electric field represent the external electric field or the net electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, dielectric, dipole

Let's assume we have dielectric material and we apply an external electric field that acts on it (let's call it E<sub>x</sub> ) . As a resault we get dipoles who in turn create another electric field (let's call it E<sub>p</sub> ) in opposite direction relative to E<sub>x</sub> and thus we get a net field (let's call it E<sub>n</sub> ) that equals to E<sub>n</sub>=E<sub>x</sub>-E<sub>p</sub>.

In Maxwell's equations we have D and E (electric displacement field and electric field) where D=ε<sub>0</sub>E+P , now my question is what should we substitute in E? is it E<sub>x</sub> or E<sub>n</sub> ?

Comment: There is only one electric field..

Comment: Is it Ex or En ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E$ in the relation $D=\epsilon_0 E + P$ is the net electric field. It is the sum of all contributions to electric field, thus sum of all partial electric fields due to all sources. In your notation, it is $E_n$.

Answer (score 1):

The net electric field is the field denoted by $E$ in Maxwell's equations.