# Is the electric field between plates of a capacitor change with Polarization charge

Tags: electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

We have a capacitor which has a dielectric between the plates in a constant voltage so it ha an electric field $$E_o$$ .

After hours we **disconnect the battery** so the new field between the plates will be :

$$ E_{new} = \frac{E_o}{ε_r} $$

My question is that the new field is related with polarization charges(the charges of the dipole )
If we increase these charges will the new electric field be decreased and this is the electric field which is related to electric susceptibility $$ D = ε_r * E $$ ?

Comment: If you disconnect the batterie E stays the same, why di you think it changes?

Comment: because there is a depolarisation field with different direction due to dielectric so the new electric field between the plates will be  E = E_o - E_dep that was my thought

Comment: But the dielectric was between the plates with the batterie and did the same.

Comment: I agree but this electric field ( E = E_o -E_dep) will not replace the old E_o between the plates?

Comment: How you describe the electric field does not count, it stays the same if the batterie is away

Comment: and this field E = E_o - E_dep which actually is?

I found also this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775122/in-maxwells-equations-concerning-dielectric-materials-does-the-electric-field

Comment: and in this link also http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dielec.html
Excuse me if I insist I am trying to understand my mistake

Comment: I don't see anything new in the two links. the dielectric is polarised, no matter if you have the batterie connected or not. The  charges on the plates stay the same. so E inside  is always U/d+P with and without batterie.

Comment: thank you now I see